# Vagrant: Pruning invalid NFS exports. Administrator privileges will be required

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox

While i am trying to run:
vagrant up i got the following

```
[default] Running provisioner: file...
[default] Forcing shutdown of VM...
[default] Destroying VM and associated drives...
Pruning invalid NFS exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
[default] Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
[default] Running cleanup tasks for 'file' provisioner...
[default] Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
[default] Running cleanup tasks for 'puppet' provisioner...
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/net/scp.rb:392:in `await_response_state': scp: ~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/net/scp.rb:363:in `block (3 levels) in start_command'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:311:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:311:in `process'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:217:in `block in preprocess'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:217:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:217:in `preprocess'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:200:in `process'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:164:in `block in loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:164:in `loop'
.
.
.
.
.
```

I am using the following versions:
ubuntu 14.04LTS
Vagrant 1.4.3
Virtualbox 4.3.36

these are my tries but no luck:

```
sudo rm /etc/exports
sudo touch /etc/exports

vagrant halt
vagrant up --provision

$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue resolved by running the following commands.

Remove and create new exports file:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/exports
$ sudo touch /etc/exports
```

Destroy the current VM machine:

```
$ sudo vagrant global-status
$ sudo vagrant destroy 26ec2cc
```

Up the vagrant with provison

```
$ sudo vagrant up --provision
```

Comment: After beating my head against the keyboard for two hours, killing the /var/exports file worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You are using somewhat outdated versions of both Vagrant and Virtualbox.

As of this posting, the current version of Vagrant is [1.8.1](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) and the current version of Virtualbox is [5.0.16](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). As a first step, I would try upgrading both of those components and retrying your vagrant up.

Beyond that, what exactly is the problem you are experiencing?

> Vagrant: Pruning invalid NFS exports. Administrator privileges will be required

Is not an error or a problem in and of itself...